# use item id in includes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code

```js
function test(value, inx) {
    if (data.itemIds.includes(value.id)) {
        var a = '<option style="font-size: 10px" data-id="e" data-product="dd" value="dd">' + value.name + '<span></span></option></select>';
        $(".test" + index).append(a);
    }
    $('.item').select2();
}
```

but whenever I use

```
if(data.itemIds.includes(value.id))
```

it gives me false ( I have for example value.id = 4 )

but when I use

```
if(data.itemIds.includes(4))
```

it gives me true!!!

how can I work on this like

> value.id

here is data.itemIds

```
(3) ["9", "10", "4"]
```

and value

```
id: 9, shop_id: 3, name: "موبایل", price: 0, status: "enable", …}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what value of `data.itemIds` is?  It would be extremely helpful in answering this question.

Comment: Can you add how `value` args looks like ? This one `test(value, inx)`

Comment: @AlexanderNied its not about `data.itemIds` its about what passed to the `test` function. Because OP used `if(data.itemIds.includes(4))` its working fine. So its about `value.id`

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Ah, fair point, I failed to note that.

Comment: Seems to me that `data.itemIds` is not a simple array of string or number . The array containing objects like structure.. How will `.includes` work in this case?

Comment: @bron1010 No that's not the case.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I've added it to question

Comment: With the data provided, `data.itemIds.includes(4)` returns `false` not `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of strings.

`["9", "10", "4"]`

And you are checking for a number

`if(data.itemIds.includes(value.id))`

Try

`data.itemIds.includes(value.id.toString())`

Answer (score 0):

Seems `data.itemIds` is array of string & `value.id` may be an integer. Change data type and then use `includes`

```js
console.log(["9", "10", "4"].includes(4)) // false
console.log(["9", "10", "4"].includes('4')) //true
```